# How to assign php variable to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  products_zipcode FROM products ")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $zip = $row['products_zipcode'];
}
?>
```

here how to assign $zip variable  value to java script variable   `var address = zip;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function codeAddress(zip) {

  var address = zip;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
</script >
```

Here changed the code 
as 
per the answers

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("coachup_db1") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  products_zipcode FROM products ")or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $zip[] = $row['products_zipcode'];

// echo("codeAddress($zip)");
}
?>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <style>
    #map-canvas {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
         border: 0px; padding: 0px;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {

  var address = <?php echo json_encode($zip); ?>;
  var overallcontent = <?php echo json_encode($zip); ?>;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', codeAddress);

    </script>
```

Comment: `var address = "<?php echo $zip; ?>";`

Comment: I dont know how often this question was answered in the one month im registered on SO.

Comment: pd: since finally you are getting a javascript array i think u need to iterate using a loop to get all the zip code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can assign a php variable to a javascript variable using the following method.

```
var address =<?php echo json_encode($zip) ?>;
```

on the other hand if you want to assign a php array to a javascript variable than:

```
var overallcontent = <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>;
```

where `$type` is a php array.

Comment: Though it's safer to use `json_encode` to prevent code injection.

Comment: Not only with array, use it with *all* variables, as explained in the countless answers to the countless questions of the same kind.

Answer (score 1):

```
var address = "<?php echo $zip ?>";
```

Comment: I dont think this will work in doublequotes, php interpreter doesnt recognize the php-tags in doublequotes.

Comment: @YUNOWORK it will work ,the server starts executing the php scripts when it first encounters the<?php tag so i dont think double quotes will make any difference.

Comment: hm ok, didnt know that, i thought he wont react to the php tags.^^

Answer (score 0):

Simply `echo` it and store it in a JavaScript variable. Here's how:

```
var address = "<?php echo $zipCode' ?>";
```